# How fast does the series $\sum_{n = n_0} ^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ decay in $n_0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is known $\sum_{n = n_0} ^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. It is also easy to see if $n_0$ increases, the tail of the sum decreases. How fast does this decay happen? In other words, is there an inequality stating something like
$$
\sum_{n = n_0} ^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac{C}{n_0}
$$
with $C > 0$ being some constant independent of $n_0$?